Commit to Work Item Link Between AZURE DEVOPS Servers Fails
I am attempting to migrate a commit link from an old Azure DevOps server to a new internal Azure DevOps server. The goal is to link a specific commit from the repository on the old server to a Work Item on the new server using an ArtifactLink relation. Despite following the Azure DevOps API documentation and sending a properly structured PATCH request to the new server, the commit link is not being added successfully to the Work Item.
    import requests
import json
import base64

# Azure DevOps connection details
organization_name = "DefaultCollection"
project_name = "Nativ-Clearance-API"
project = "2379ab9f-dae0-4f6e-9f52-2e3f746d64d8"
work_item_id = 24594  # The ID of the work item you want to update
repository_id_get = "0a149557-bd34-480c-b9de-37f972aca43c"
repository_id_post ="f87dde0c-4a19-4693-81b6-44400390f5cf"
commit_id = "e888f8744e2cc40d43e2e3eaf91805a2d0ac4fa9"  # The commitId you want to add
personal_access_token = "**************"  # Replace with your personal access token
base64_encoded_token = base64.b64encode(f":{personal_access_token}".encode()).decode("utf-8")

import requests
import json
from base64 import b64encode

# Old server data
old_server = {
    "organization": "HMS-RD",
    "project": "Nativ-Clearance-API",
    "repo_id": "0a149557-bd34-480c-b9de-37f972aca43c",  # Repository ID from the old server
    "commit_id": "1489545200cdf2f0d0852ce129bb31f21ddcad07",  # Commit ID
    "personal_access_token": "**************"  # Replace with the old server's PAT
}

# New server data
new_server = {
    "url": "http://192.168.1.132//DefaultCollection",
    "project": "Nativ-Clearance-API",
    "repo_id": "f87dde0c-4a19-4693-81b6-44400390f5cf",  # Define new repository ID in the internal server
    "work_item_id": 24594,
    "personal_access_token": "**************"  # Replace with the new server's PAT
}

# Step 1: Authentication with the old server and fetching commit_id
old_commit_url = f"https://dev.azure.com/{old_server['organization']}/{old_server['project']}/_apis/git/repositories/{old_server['repo_id']}/commits/{old_server['commit_id']}?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
old_headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Basic {b64encode(f':{old_server['personal_access_token']}'.encode()).decode()}"
}

# Sending the request to the old server
response = requests.get(old_commit_url, headers=old_headers)
if response.status_code == 200:
    commit_data = response.json()
    print("Commit data fetched successfully!")
else:
    print(f"Failed to fetch commit data: {response.status_code}")
    print(response.text)
    exit()

# Step 2: Sending PATCH request to the new server to link commit to the work item
new_work_item_url = f"{new_server['url']}/{new_server['project']}/_apis/wit/workitems/{new_server['work_item_id']}?api-version=7.1-preview.2"
new_headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json",
    "Authorization": f"Basic {b64encode(f':{new_server['personal_access_token']}'.encode()).decode()}"
}

# Payload to link commit to the work item
payload = [
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/relations/-",
        "value": {
            "rel": "ArtifactLink",
            "url": f"vstfs:///Git/{new_server['repo_id']}/commit/{old_server['commit_id']}",
            "attributes": {
                "comment": "Migrated commit link from old server",
                "name": "Nativ-Clearance-API"
            }
        }
    }
]

# Sending the request to the new server
response = requests.patch(new_work_item_url, headers=new_headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Commit successfully linked to work item!")
else:
    print(f"Failed to link commit: {response.status_code}")
    print(response.text)


Refer to this link  to Get Work Item and Refer to link to  Add Comment

Below code is to migrate a commit id  between Azure DevOps servers and merge it to a work item.
Refer this link  to Create   Work Items  with  REST API in Azure DevOps
Refer this doc to  Link git commit or branch to work item via command line.
import requests
import base64
import json
old_org_url = "https://old-server.dev.azure.com/organization_name"
new_org_url = "https://new-server.dev.azure.com/organization_name"
old_pat = "OLD_PAT" 
new_pat = "NEW_PAT"  
api_version = "7.1"
def get_headers(pat):
    token = base64.b64encode(f":{pat}".encode("ascii")).decode("ascii")
    return {
        "Authorization": f"Basic {token}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

old_headers = get_headers(old_pat)
new_headers = get_headers(new_pat)

def get_commit_details(org_url, project, repository_id, commit_id, headers):
    url = f"{org_url}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repository_id}/commits/{commit_id}?api-version={api_version}"
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        print(f"Error fetching commit details: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
        return None

link_commit_to_work_item(org_url, project, work_item_id, commit_url, headers):
    url = f"{org_url}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{work_item_id}?api-version={api_version}"
    body = [
        {
            "op": "add",
            "path": "/relations/-",
            "value": {
                "rel": "ArtifactLink",
                "url": commit_url,
                "attributes": {"name": "Fixed in Commit"}
            }
        }
    ]
    response = requests.patch(url, headers=headers, json=body)
    if response.status_code in [200, 201]:
        return response.json()
    else:
        print(f"Error linking commit to work item: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
        return None
def migrate_commit_link(old_org_url, new_org_url, old_headers, new_headers, old_project, new_project, work_item_id, repository_id, commit_id):
    commit_details = get_commit_details(old_org_url, old_project, repository_id, commit_id, old_headers)
    if not commit_details:
        print("Failed to retrieve commit details from the old server.")
        return
    commit_url = commit_details["_links"]["web"]["href"]
    print(f"Commit URL from old server: {commit_url}")
    result = link_commit_to_work_item(new_org_url, new_project, work_item_id, commit_url, new_headers)
    if result:
        print("Successfully linked commit to the work item on the new server.")
        print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
    else:
        print("Failed to link the commit to the work item.")
old_project = "OldProjectName"
new_project = "NewProjectName"
repository_id = "OldRepositoryID"  
commit_id = "CommitID"  
work_item_id = 123  
migrate_commit_link(
    old_org_url,
    new_org_url,
    old_headers,
    new_headers,
    old_project,
    new_project,
    work_item_id,
    repository_id,
    commit_id
)

Output:

